# Should we add "to" after the word "host" or not?

Tags: expressions

***The first sentence:***

> Since its opening in 1973, the Sydney Opera House has been ***host to*** many of the most memorable, world-class artistic performances.

***The second sentence:***

> Which country is going to host the next World Cup?

Both the two sentences are correct. But I notice that the first sentence has a word "to" after "host", yet the second doesn't have. So when should I add "to" after "host"? Are both the expressions right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences are correct.

The most crucial thing of your confusion is perhaps you are not aware of the fact that *"host"* in the first sentence is a **noun**, and *"host"* in the second sentence is a **verb**. I trust that you will have no problem with ***"to"*** once you can see that.

The big clue for the first sentence is *"... has been **host** to ..."*. If this *"host"* is a verb, it would have been *"... has been **hosting** ..."*. But it's not, so it's a noun.

In the second sentence *"... is going to **host** ..."*, this *"host"* must be a verb; if you want *"host"* to be a noun in this sentence, you will need to say *"... is going to **be the host** ..."*

---

You can find the definition of the word *"host"* in [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/host). For your first sentence,

> *noun (5)* - an area in which particular plants or animals are found:
>   *Australia is host to some of the world’s most dangerous animals*

and for your second sentence,

> *verb (1)* - act as host at (an event) or for (a television or radio programme):
>   *Canada was asked to host a Commonwealth conference in Ottawa*

Answer (score 1):

When *host* is being used as a verb, and you are describing the event that was taking place, then *host* is a transitive verb and the event is its direct object:

> I hosted a party.
>
> Reykjavik will host the next Winter Olympics.

However, *host* may also be used as a noun, especially an attributive noun; generally it is used as the object of the sentence, in which case you then need a prepositional phrase (usually starting with *to* or *of*) to describe the event (or the people) who had a host:

> John was the host of the party.
>
> I played host to half a dozen exchange students.
>
> Sydney Opera House has been host to many memorable performances.

Answer (score 0):

The content in this answer was taken from [Grammar Monster](http://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/too_to.htm).

> **To** has two uses:
>
> **To** is used in expressions like `to walk`, `to run`, `to paint`, etc. (These are all verbs in their infinitive forms.)
>
> - I want to run around the planet.
> - Did you tell her what to think?
>
> I'm glad **to hear** you smoke. A man should always have an occupation of some kind. There are far too many idle men in London as it is.   (Oscar Wilde)
>
> ---
>
> **To** is used in expressions like to the park, to the postman, agree to a proposal. (The word to in these examples is a preposition.)
>
> - She handed the parcel to the stranger.
> - I am going to the park.

Answer (score -1):

To cut it short in this context:

> **'host to'** means things have already happened at that place (*.....host to many of the most memorable, world-class artistic performances* - performances **already** happened*).

And,

> **'to host'** means yet/likely to occur/happen at that place (*....country is going to host the next World Cup?* - The event **hasn't happened yet.**)

So, use *host to* when you want to show that things or events have already happened at that place and when it's arranged or planned to happen at that place, use *to host*.

Comment: Any reason why it is down voted? What am I missing?